# iOS Settings - Notifications: How to remove my App if I do not use local notifications?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I removed the use of local notifications from my app, but it still appears in the iOS Settings -> Notifications. If I do not use local notifications, it makes no sense to show the app in the settings.

Is there a key in info.plist or anything that I have to delete?
The deployment target is iOS 7.0.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you register for remote notifications?

Comment: Push Notifications is disabled in my App ID. Is there any other place I have to look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to unregister user notification settings (iOS8+) by calling

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:nil];
}
```

Comment: The deployment target is iOS 7.0. I updated my question. Any other ideas?

Comment: Great! You saved my day. Run the app with your code and the app disappeared from the settings. After that, removed the code snippet. Thanks! :)

Comment: Just modified my code to work on older OS versions (i.e. <=iOS7)